# 8 red balls, 2 blue balls, probability that 2 blues aren't next to each other

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Here's a problem I thought of. Say I have $10$ balls that are randomly arranged in a row: $8$ red and $2$ blue. Find the probability that the $2$ blue balls aren't adjacent.

There are $9$ configurations where the $2$ blues are adjacent, and a total of $\binom{10}{2} = 45$ configurations. So the probability should be $(45 - 9)/45 = 4/5$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total number of arrangements:

$\frac{10!}{8!2!} = 45$

Number of arrangements blue balls are adjacent (we group blue balls together as one object):

$\frac{9!}{8!} = 9$

Number of arrangements blue balls are not adjacent:

$45 - 9 = 36$

Probability blue balls are not adjacent:

$\frac{36}{45} = \frac45$

Got the same answer, looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can also count the non-adjacent possibilities instead of using complement.

Arrange the red balls first. There are $9$ places to put blue ball, either first, last, or between two red balls. So there are $\binom{9}{2}$ possibilities.

$$
\frac{\binom{9}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}}=
\frac{4}{5}
$$